# I got the message coordinate (,) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter while loading the data from csv file. Any help?

Tags: coordinates

Snippet of my code:

```
\newcommand*{\datafile}{sr_data_test.csv}

\addplot [color=blue, solid, line width=1.0pt, mark size=3.0pt, mark=x, mark options={solid}]
table[x index =0, y index = 1, col sep=comma]{\datafile};
\addlegendentry{303.15K};
```

Comment: Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you for asking example and I posted the example at the question "Reading of a column for four grpahs with same x-values causes coordinates has been droped because of a coordinate filter. Any help?" Hopping that my issue will be resolved, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The snippet works fine:

```
\newcommand*{\datafile}{sr_data_test.csv}

\begin{filecontents*}{\datafile}
x,y
1,0
2,3
3,4
4,3
5,2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[
      color=blue,
      solid,
      line width=1.0pt,
      mark size=3.0pt,
      mark=x,
      mark options={solid}
    ] table[
      x index=0,
      y index=1,
      col sep=comma
    ]{\datafile};
    \addlegendentry{303.15K};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]